# How to write multiple conditions of if-statement in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I have trouble writing `if` conditions in Robot Framework.

I want to execute

```
Run Keyword If '${color}' == 'Red' OR '${color}' == 'Blue'  OR '${color}' == 'Pink'    Check the quantity
```

I can use this "`Run keyword If`" keyword with one condition, but for more than one conditions, I got this error:

> FAIL: Keyword name cannot be empty.

And also I would like to use these keywords:

```
Run Keyword If '${color} == 'Blue' AND '${Size} == 'Small' AND '${Design}' != '${Simple}'      Check the quantity
```

And

```
Run Keyword Unless '${color}' == 'Black' OR '${Size}' == 'Small' OR '${Design}' == 'Simple'
```

But I just end up getting errors.

Comment: Since you're OR'ing your conditions, you could just use 3 `Run Keyword If` statements.

Comment: Try `Run Keyword If '${color}' in ['Red', 'Blue', 'Pink'] Check the quantity`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Can help me answer the edited part as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should use small caps "or" and "and" instead of OR and AND.

And beware also the spaces/tabs between keywords and arguments (you need at least two spaces).

Here is a code sample with your three keywords working fine:

Here is the file `ts.txt`:

```
  *** test cases ***
  mytest
    ${color} =  set variable  Red
    Run Keyword If  '${color}' == 'Red'  log to console  \nexecuted with single condition
    Run Keyword If  '${color}' == 'Red' or '${color}' == 'Blue' or '${color}' == 'Pink'  log to console  \nexecuted with multiple or

    ${color} =  set variable  Blue
    ${Size} =  set variable  Small
    ${Simple} =  set variable  Simple
    ${Design} =  set variable  Simple
    Run Keyword If  '${color}' == 'Blue' and '${Size}' == 'Small' and '${Design}' != '${Simple}'  log to console  \nexecuted with multiple and

    ${Size} =  set variable  XL
    ${Design} =  set variable  Complicated
    Run Keyword Unless  '${color}' == 'Black' or '${Size}' == 'Small' or '${Design}' == 'Simple'  log to console  \nexecuted with unless and multiple or
```

and here is what I get when I execute it:

```
$ pybot ts.txt
==============================================================================
Ts
==============================================================================
mytest                                                                .
executed with single condition
executed with multiple or
executed with unless and multiple or
mytest                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can i give three or more 'or' will it work? or only two 'or' is allowed in robot if conditions?

Comment: @Mia, You can give multiple 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure put single space before and after "and" Keyword..

Comment: you can add this as comment its not an answer!

Answer (score -2):

The below code worked fine:

```
Run Keyword if    '${value1}' \ \ == \ \ '${cost1}' \ and \ \ '${value2}' \ \ == \ \ 'cost2'    LOG    HELLO
```