# How do I use Robot Frame Ride execute branch statements?

Tags: robotframework

I'm using the Robot Framework Ride to run a test.
This is the test case structure:

```
if A>B:
   print 1
   print 2
   print 3
if C>D:
   print 4
   print 5
```

I didn't find a way to execute multiple commands below one `if`. I found one keyword `Run Keyword if`, but it can only execute one statement.

Comment: RIDE is just an IDE for editing robot framework tests. You question applies to robot framework, not RIDE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write multiple conditions of if / else in robot framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863264/how-to-write-multiple-conditions-of-if-else-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many robot framework keywords related to conditional steps. The most common one is [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If). If you want to run multiple commands you can combine that with [Run keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords).

For example:

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | run keyword if | ${a} > ${B} | Run keywords
| | ... | log to console | 1
| | ... | AND | log to console | 2
| | ... | AND | log to console | 3
```

The [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) documents all of the keywords that come with robot framework.

Comment: Hi Bryan Oakley, Thanks for your answer. I will do interface test with RF ride. So there are right and wrong parameter。when with right parameter, I want to get feedback and sure the content, if with wrong parameter, just prompt "wrong parameter".  so help me how to resolve this case, thanks

Comment: my test case as below:                                                                                  ******************************************************************************************create http context host=www.jucaicat.net:80 scheme=http 
get /jcc818/ContactUsInfo  
${response_status} get response status  
should start with ${response_status} 200 
${body} get response body  
${temp} get json value ${body} /weibo_desc 
${title} get json value ${body} /title 
${ret_phone_desc}= get json value ${body} /phone_desc
should be equal ${ret_phone_desc} "400-050-1889

Comment: My test case can test right parameter, but if with wrong parameter, will prompt wrong.