# Syntax for Run Keyword If with multiple negative conditions

Tags: selenium, robotframework

**I want to construct Run Keyword if in such a way so that it can handle multiple negative conditions**

I took help in constructing Run Keyword if for multiple conditions in the following way:

```
Run keyword if   ${Param1} in ['${value1}', '${value2}]    Log to Console   Some Message
```

> Help taken from: [How to write multiple conditions of if-statement in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23863264/10982633)

**Now I want to construct the same function so that the keyword runs if few conditions are not met.**

The obvious code can be as follows:
Run keyword if   ${Param1}!=${value1} and ${Param1}!=${value2}   Log to Console    Some Message

**The code that I am expecting:**

```
Run keyword if   ${Param1} !in  ['${value1}', '${value2}]    Log to Console   Some Message
```

What is the correct syntax for `!in`?

Comment: use the keyword `not in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `not in`, and you also need to make sure there is only a single space after `in`, and make sure you properly quote your values:

```
Run keyword if   '${Param1}' not in ['${value1}', '${value2}']    
...  Log to Console   Some Message
```

if any of the variables could themselves have quotes, you can use the variables directly in the expression by omitting the curly brackets, like so:

```
Run keyword if   $Param1 not in [$value1, $value2]    
...  Log to Console   Some Message
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. The extra piece of information(variable can be used directly if they have quotes) was not known to me. Thanks for the knowledge :) Have a great day!