# How to make Run Keyword If work with 'OR'?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to use `Run Keyword If` with **or** but for some reason it does not work and I could not understand why. It shows me an error *No keyword with name 'or' found*. I assume there is some syntax error. I also tried with **OR** but it did not work.

```
Keyword 1
Check Walkthrough Guide Opened
Go to    ${WALKTHROUGH_URL}
Open Walkthrough Guide If It's Closed
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${WELCOME_POPUP}    ${WFE_TIMEOUT}
Page Should Contain Element    ${POPUP_TITLE}

Keyword 2
${ELEMS}=    Execute JavaScript    return localStorage.getItem('peopleAnalyticsTourDismiss')
Run Keyword If    ('${ELEMS}' == 'true')  or  (${ELEMS}' == 'None')   Run Keywords
...    Execute Javascript    localStorage.setItem('peopleAnalyticsTourDismiss', 'false')
...    AND    Reload Page
```

Comment: You have received two answers both of them solving your problem. Please consider accepting one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the two spaces on either side of "or" to a single space. Robot sees the two or more spaces and thinks "or" is the keyword to run.

```
Run Keyword If    ('${ELEMS}' == 'true')  or  (${ELEMS}' == 'None')   Run Keywords
#                                       ^^  ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Robot Framework is understanding your **OR** as the second argument of the keyword **Run Keyword If**. Switch the double spaces for a single one, like the example below:

```
Run Keyword If    ('${ELEMS}' == 'true') or (${ELEMS}' == 'None')   Run Keywords
```

This way, robot will understand `('${ELEMS}' == 'true') or (${ELEMS}' == 'None')` as just one argument of **Run Keyword If**, with is the condition one.

If you still have doubts, I've found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23870640/15282708) with a similar problem, and a good solution as an example.

Other thing that can be giving you some trouble, is that you missed a `'` in the beggining of the second comparison: `or (${ELEMS}' == 'None')`. Try changing it for one of the options below:
`or ('${ELEMS}' == 'None')`
`or ("${ELEMS}" == "None")`
`or ("""${ELEMS}""" == """None""")`

Please refer to the [Builtin](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) library for doubts about triple quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Still the same error.

Comment: @oksa23 I've just updated my answer, adding another possible solution that can help you, please check it :)